# Saving a photo Access database record (using TableAdapter in Vis.Basic '15)

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm creating a program where I add information about people to an Access database from VB.net on Visual Studio 2017 Community.
The way it works is, I will be using two tab pages in the form (one for adding the record; the other for updating). I'm not having any problems adding the actual record or updating it, so nothing to worry on that.

My main plan is to add an image to each new or existing record and save the images on there, so that the person's image will be displayed onto the picture box in the update tab if that person's record is selected.

Here is my code for the 'Browse' button when I add a record:

```
OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "images files (*.bmp;*.jpg;*.gif;*.png)|*.bmp;*.jpg;*.gif;*.png"

 If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        PicPictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
 Else
   MessageBox.Show("Nothing was selected.")
 End If
```

And the code for when I add a record to the db:

```
Dim birthdate As Date            
Date.TryParse(AddBirth.Text, birthdate)

TblFriendsTableAdapter.AddNewRow(AddFirstName.Text, AddLastName.Text,
                                             AddState.Text, txtAddCity.Text,
                                              AddCountry.Text, txtAddPhone.Text,
                                               AddInterest.Text, birthdate, PicPictureBox.Image.ToString)
Me.Validate()
Me.TblFriendsBindingSource.EndEdit()
TblFriendsTableAdapter.Update(FriendsDataSet.tblFriends)
Me.TblFriendsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.FriendsDataSet.tblFriends)
```

Initially, when the record is added, the image is "saved" to the database but is only read on the picture field as System.Drawing.Bitmap. 
Should I use file paths on my code instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save and retrieve the image then you will need to actually store the image itself.  When you call `ToString` on an `Image` object you just get the fully qualified type as a string (which is why you are seeing `System.Drawing.Bitmap`).  So what you need to do is to save the image in a binary format into you database.  You can use a BLOB (`oleObject`) field to hold the image data.  Note that this does have some pitfalls, one of which is that it will greatly increase the size of your DB.  To get the image data, just use the `Save` method of the `Image` class.  You can save the data to a [MemoryStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream(v=vs.110).aspx) and then grab the `bytes` from the stream to store in your database.

To further clarify why you should be storing the image information (either in the DB or in some other file system location that you have access to) think about what happens if you are just storing the location that was chosen from the UI.  The image could be replaced on the file system, the image could be deleted, if you access the database (and your app) from another machine the image isn't there (or some other image has the same local file path and again is not what you expected).

Here is a snippet in VB showing how to get the image as a byte array.

```
Dim result As Byte()
Using ms As New MemoryStream
    PicPictureBox.Image.Save(ms, PicPictureBox.Image.RawFormat)

    result = ms.ToArray()
End Using
```

Now you can take the array and store it in your database.  When you pull it back from the DB you can just use do a similar process as the save by loading the bytes back into a `MemoryStream` and using the `Image.FromStream` method to load it.